Can't get Microsoft's ICU package working on AWS Linux 2 AMI
Background: Initial issue was some computers had 4 letter month abbreviations and some 3
https://stackoverflow.com/a/79232095/1305736
We want to eliminate future inconsistencies by moving to app-local ICU on our framework-dependent app
Based off Microsoft documentation, we made the following .csproj changes
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/globalization-icu#app-local-icu
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ICU.ICU4C.Runtime" Version="72.1.0.3" />
...
    <InvariantGlobalization>false</InvariantGlobalization>
...

  <ItemGroup>
    <IcuAssemblies Include="icu\*.so*" />
    <RuntimeTargetsCopyLocalItems Include="@(IcuAssemblies)" AssetType="native" CopyLocal="true"
      DestinationSubDirectory="runtimes/linux-x64/native/"
      DestinationSubPath="%(FileName)%(Extension)"
      RuntimeIdentifier="linux-x64" NuGetPackageId="Microsoft.ICU.ICU4C.Runtime" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <RuntimeHostConfigurationOption Include="System.Globalization.UseNls" Value="false" />
    <RuntimeHostConfigurationOption Include="System.Globalization.AppLocalIcu" Value="72.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

This works on Windows 10, 11 and our build server running RHEL9
However once we deploy to AWS's Linux 2 AMI it fails to start
sudo journalctl --unit=myAppApi.service -n 100 --no-pager

systemd[1]: Started My App .NET Core WebApp with systemd.
Process terminated. Failed to load app-local ICU: libicudata.so.72.1
at System.Environment.FailFast(System.String)
at System.Globalization.GlobalizationMode.LoadLibrary(System.String, Boolean)
at System.Globalization.GlobalizationMode.LoadAppLocalIcuCore(System.ReadOnlySpan`1<Char>, System.ReadOnlySpan`1<Char>)
at System.Globalization.GlobalizationMode.LoadAppLocalIcu(System.String)
at System.Globalization.GlobalizationMode+Settings..cctor()
at System.Globalization.CultureData.CreateCultureWithInvariantData()
at System.Globalization.CultureData.get_Invariant()
at System.Globalization.TextInfo..cctor()
at System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource.GetGuid(System.Type)
at System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource..ctor(System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSourceSettings, System.String[])
at System.Net.NetEventSource..cctor()
at System.Net.Quic.MsQuicApi..cctor()
at System.Net.Quic.QuicListener.get_IsSupported()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilderQuicExtensions.UseQuic(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostBuilder)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilderQuicExtensions.UseQuic(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostBuilder, System.Action`1<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Quic.QuicTransportOptions>)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilderKestrelExtensions.UseKestrel(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostBuilder, System.Action`2<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilderContext,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerOptions>)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebHost.ConfigureWebDefaults(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostBuilder)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(System.String[])
at Company.MyApp.Program.CreateWebHostBuilder(System.String[])
at Company.MyApp.Program.Main(System.String[])
systemd[1]: myAppApi.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=6/ABRT
systemd[1]: Unit myAppApi.service entered failed state.
systemd[1]: myAppApi.service failed.

The build process does what I expect it to
i.e. the publish\runtimes\linux-x64\native is populated with correct files
Removing the RuntimeHostConfigurationOption configuration and the app runs just fine
I'm out of ideas given the lack of detail in error logs from starting the service

I've been working on making our .NET Core app use app-local ICU to avoid future inconsistencies, following Microsoft's documentation. Here’s the relevant part of our .csproj file:
enter code here

<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ICU.ICU4C.Runtime" Version="72.1.0.3" />
<InvariantGlobalization>true</InvariantGlobalization>
<ItemGroup>
<IcuAssemblies Include="icu\*.so*" />
<RuntimeTargetsCopyLocalItems Include="@(IcuAssemblies)" AssetType="native" 
 CopyLocal="true"
 DestinationSubDirectory="runtimes/linux-x64/native/"
 DestinationSubPath="%(FileName)%(Extension)"
 RuntimeIdentifier="linux-x64" NuGetPackageId="Microsoft.ICU.ICU4C.Runtime" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<RuntimeHostConfigurationOption Include="System.Globalization.UseNls" 
 Value="false" />
<RuntimeHostConfigurationOption Include="System.Globalization.AppLocalIcu" 
 Value="72.1" />
</ItemGroup>

This setup works fine on Windows 10/11 and our build server running RHEL 9. However, when we deploy the app to Amazon Linux 2 (AL2), it crashes on startup. The journalctl log from systemd shows the following:
enter code here
 test-server.internal myApp[2736]: at MyApp.Program.Main(String[] args) in 
 MyApp\Program.cs:line 15
 test-server.internal systemd[1]: myApi.service: main process exited, 
 code=killed, status=6/ABRT
 test-server.internal systemd[1]: Unit myApi.service entered failed state.
 test-server.internal systemd[1]: myApi.service failed.

I also noticed other warnings/errors related to the systemd service file, but removing the ICU-related settings (RuntimeHostConfigurationOption) allows the app to run just fine.
Here’s what I’ve already checked:

The publish/runtimes/linux-x64/native directory contains the correct ICU files (libicuuc.so.72, libicudata.so.72, etc.).
Running ldd on the .so files resolves all dependencies on AL2.
Running the app manually (outside of systemd) still fails when using app-local ICU, so it doesn't seem like a systemd issue.
I’ve confirmed the app works fine with the default ICU globalization settings on AL2.
My systemd service file looks like this:


enter code here
[Unit]
Description=MyApp .NET Core WebApp
After=network.target
Wants=network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/app
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /path/to/app/MyApp.dll
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Training
Environment=ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:5000

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Also I need to know
What could cause the app to crash on Amazon Linux 2 with app-local ICU?
and are there any extra steps or dependencies required for AL2 that aren’t mentioned in the Microsoft docs?
